# using fileProvider from service context

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fileprovider

I want to show a notification and when user clicked install an APK file.
I know how to use the fileProvider itself but I have problem with ***service*** context.

Here is my code
manifest:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.company.app"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
```

filePaths:

```
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="externalFiles"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

service Code:

```
resultIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        Uri uri;
                        File file = FileHelper.getApkFile(item.getLink());
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
                            uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                                    NotificationService.this,
                                    NotificationService.this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
                                    file);
                            NotificationService.this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,
                                    resultIntent);
                        } else {
                            uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                        }


                        resultIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                        resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

as you know *setResult()* is not available in service.

**How can I grant permission from service context?**

thank you every one.

Comment: what do you want to do with `resultIntent` in your `Service`?

Comment: I want to create a pendingIntent based on that and show a notification.

Comment: and what do you have problems with?

Comment: I can NOT call setResult() in service it belongs to Activity

Comment: why would you call `setResult()` in Activity? if you want to show a `Notification` use `NotificationManager`

Comment: I use setResult() to grant permission for the destination app(if I comment that the other app can NOT load the file)

Comment: then use `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`

Comment: for the PendingIntent or Intent?

Comment: I add that flag to my intent but it is not working

Comment: Then what happens instead?

Comment: `(if I comment that the other app can NOT load the file) –` ??? Then do not comment. And if the other app can read the file then what is the poblem? I do not understand the whole thing. And i certainly do not understand why you ever would call setResult from a service. Would you invoke onActivityResult??

Comment: i have no idea what `"not working"` really means...

Comment: new activity starts to install the apk file but the permission for the app is not granted as a result the installation page closes immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem

I had to add this permission to my manifest to install apk file.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```